# Canonical way to simulate a file manager "open item" from the command line

Tags: desktop-environment, file-opening

Almost every desktop environment has a mechanism for determining what to do when you (double)-click a file in file manager/explorer windows. This can be based on the extension, or on whatever `file` does, etc.

Now, suppose I have a terminal window open within a desktop session and I'm at some folder. Is there some binary or script - hopefully valid across multiple desktop environments common to Linux - which, when executed with a filename as its argument, uses this mechanism and has the same effect as (double)-clicking that file would?

If there isn't a single multi-desktop-environment way to do this - are there a bunch of desktop-environment-specific binaries/scripts with this functionality? If so, can you list such a bunch?

On Windows I think this exists in the form of the [`start` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) (although, of course, they can assume a single desktop environment.)

Comment: For Ubuntu see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15354/how-to-open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line). Maybe this works for other linux too.

Comment: +1 `xdg-open` is part of the freedesktop [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) suite - so should be a bit more generic than just Ubuntu I think

Comment: You're right, thank you. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251054/how-does-the-xdg-open-command-know-which-application-to-use-to-open-a-file

Comment: @steeldriver: Make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For desktop environments that implement the [freedesktop.org xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) tools, you should be able to use `xdg-open`:

> **Name**
>
> xdg-open — opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
>   Synopsis
>
> xdg-open { file | URL }
>
> xdg-open { --help | --manual | --version } Description
>
> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>   browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the
>   preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file,
>   ftp, http and https URLs.
>
> xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not
>   recommended to use xdg-open as root.
>
> **Options**
>
> --help
>       Show command synopsis.
>
> --manual
>       Show this manual page.
>
> --version
>       Show the xdg-utils version information.